# Changing name of the file to download

Tags: gnome, nautilus, filemanager

After I choose a file to download and pick a destination, I need to rename the file. But when I start typing, it activates the searching bar, [image: picture] even though the name of the file is highlighted. It becomes annoying, when I work with a lot of files. I use searching bar twice per year. Is there a way to not get to the searching bar and rather to the name of the file immediately when I start typing?

EDIT:

When I choose the destination I use main/central part of file explorer as in the second image [image]