# Unable to change the name of file being downloaded

Tags: gnome, xdg

This question is a blatant duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280653/changing-name-of-the-file-to-download) question. However, given that the question in place is [2 years and 6 months old](https://xkcd.com/979/), and has no answers or comments, I've decided to post this again in hopes of attracting more attention.

The problem is simple: When attempting to rename a file being downloaded, any key struck changes the focus of the screen to the searching bar.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/a2W3mDH.mp4) is a webm video of what happens.

I should remark that, even after this whole endeavour (of having to repeatedly click on name form), it still failed to save

This is incredibly mildly annoying.

Is there anything that can be done?

Currently using Ubuntu 22.04.02 with Cinnamon DE. The Class name of the window (that opens when I download a file) is xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.

Comment: The snap version of Firefox placed all sorts of restrictions on downloads -- for security of course. How are you downloading?

Comment: In this specific scenario, I was just trying to save an image. Right Click -> Save Image As.

Comment: Saving an image is the same as downloading. You are trying to write something to somewhere.

Comment: why not double click on the given file name and edit it in one go to what you require. That's what Ive been doing for years without any problem. Annoying yes, but not life threatening!

Comment: Do you want to rename the file **while** it is downloading or **after** it downloaded? I have downloaded many files. they are in my downloads folder. I can right click on any of them and select rename. Or I can highlight a file and hit the **F2** key.

Comment: @user68186 I want to give the file another name BEFORE it downloads, as opposed to saving it to disk with its default name. Currently, my only solution is to download the file to disk, go to the directory where its located, and manually rename it. I want to "Save As" and simply choose the name myself.

Comment: @24601 I think you are misunderstanding. Every type i type a single letter onto the name form, the focus changes to the search bar. If I try to write the name "image.jpg", I need to write the letter 'I', click back to the name form, write the letter 'm', click back to the name form, write the letter 'a', click back.... and so on. I am unable to simply write out the name "Image.jpg"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/xdg-desktop-portal-gnome/-/issues/53) which affects the save functionality from programs installed via snap (in this instance, Firefox).

There is a workaround for Firefox. Go to "about:config" in Firefox, and set the widget.use-xdg-desktop-portal.file-picker to 0.

Answer (score 0):

My work around is to clear the current name and one at a time input the letters.
When you put your first letter in it place it takes you to search box.
Go back right click the next letter position enter next letter it takes you to search box go back and so on.
Hit Save.